# Integral on $\partial B(0,R)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

I want to calculate $\int_{\partial B(x,\epsilon)}\frac{1}{|x-y|^2}$ with $B(x,\epsilon)\in \mathbb{R}^3$

Time ago I saw a paper who said (if I am right)

$\int_{\partial B(0,R)}\frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-1}}=\omega_n/2$ ,with n the dimension of the space.

Is this correct? how can i demonstrate?

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$ \int_{\partial B(x,R)} \frac{1}{|x - y|^{n-1}} \, dS = \int_{\partial B(x,R)} \frac{1}{R^{n-1}} \, dS = \frac{1}{R^{n-1}} R^{n-1} S_{n-1} = S_{n-1} = n \cdot \omega_n $$

where $S_{n}$ is the surface area of the unit $n$-dimensional sphere and $\omega_n$ is the volume of the $n$-dimensional unit ball.